# Qt drawRect in background

Tags: c++, qt, paint, drawrect, qpainter

I want to paint the background of a slider. I tried this but the color covers up the whole slider. This is in an inherited class of QSlider

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.begin(this);
  painter.setBrush(/*not important*/);

  // This covers up the control. How do I make it so the color is in
  // the background and the control is still visible?
  painter.drawRect(rect()); 

  painter.end();
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is paint the background of a widget? Please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set the background of a widget you could set the style sheet:

```
theSlider->setStyleSheet("QSlider { background-color: green; }");
```

The following will set the background of the widget, allowing you to do more:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
  QPainter painter;
  painter.begin(this);
  painter.fillRect(rect(), /* brush, brush style or color */);
  painter.end(); 

  // This is very important if you don't want to handle _every_ 
  // detail about painting this particular widget. Without this 
  // the control would just be red, if that was the brush used, 
  // for instance.
  QSlider::paintEvent(event);    
}
```

And btw. the following two lines of your sample code will yield a warning:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.begin(this);
```

Namely this one using GCC:

> QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at
>   a time.

So make sure, as I do in my example, that you either do `QPainter painter(this)` or `painter.begin(this)`.